# how to show an image and description form mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show an image then a description under the image. I get the image show but I'm stuck with the description. I can't get that working.
Below my code to show the image and description

```
    // Get images from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY uploaded_on DESC");
$description = $db->query("SELECT * FROM description ORDER BY uploaded_on  DESC");    

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = 'upload/'.$row["file_name"];

?>

    <center><img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" /><br><p><?php      echo $description; ?></p></center>
<?php }
}else{ ?>
    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You're using the same variable for both queries; i.e. the second `$query` overwrites the first. Give both queries unique variable names. Use the result(s) from your second query to set the value of `$description`, it is not being set now.

Comment: @jibsteroos Tanks  havr try it and no errs but no text come up?

Comment: that's because variable `$description` is not set, i.e. it's empty. You need to set its value for each of the results you get back from your query.

Comment: By the way, why do you use two different tables - table `images` and table `description`; isn't it easier to have all data in one table?

Comment: @jibsteroos i thinks it is i am not though here is the mslq table (`id`, `file_name`, `description`, `uploaded_on`, `status`) and how do i set the variable thanks for the help

Comment: Well I think you need some way of connecting the description with the image?. Maybe store the image id in the description table. That way you can run a single query for fetching the image and related description

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Many times the effort of typing a post goes into reading it: please try and install a tool/plugin helping with English capitalisation, punctuation and grammar, if not orthography.

Comment: (Your "`<?…?>` *processing instruction*s" do not look well-formed.)